# how can i remove the old value of a variable when user doesn't give it a new one

Tags: batch-file

i am trying to make a program in batch.
part of that program, the user has to input a number between 1 and 5
however if he doesn't  put anything, the program takes the old value of that variable (after he put it the first time) even if i set it again to 0 (the program is on a loop)
here is an example of that part of the program:
ps: in this case i am setting manually to 0 so it loops

```
@echo off
goto bla
:bla
set /p a="a: "
if "%a%"=="" (
    goto bla
)
echo a= %a%
set /p b="b: " 
if "%b%"=="0" (
    goto bla
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> then the variable will remain unchanged.

If you `set` the variable to *empty* first, then execute the `set/p`, you can detect that condition.

```
set "var="
set /p "var=promptstring "
if not defined var echo nothing entered
```

This can be used to apply a default value:

```
set "var=37"
set /p "var=promptstring [%var%]"
if not defined var echo nothing entered
echo %var%
```

(shows the default (37) in the prompt)